# node-http-proxy proxy.on('proxyReq'...) never fires

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I am using node.js proxy. It works successfully, however:

```
proxy.on('proxyResponse', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
    console.log("hi");

});
```

Never fires even though I see in the browser my api request was proxied successfully and I successfully got my json. Why isn't the `proxyResponse` firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `proxy.on('proxyRes', ...` instead.

Comment: Thanks...is there documentation that lists the event listeners? I couldn't find a list...just random bits scattered on the readme and issue of the github repo.

Comment: Sure:
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/README.md#listening-for-proxy-events